# Laravel Dynamic Dependent Dropdown Ajax (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

This is my 1st time trying Laravel and ajax then I got stuck when calling Ajax syntax my page loads, but my Product name list doesn't show when I choose a Product category, and I receive an error on my console (Internal Server Error) every time I click the product category.
please help me

this is the code......

productlist.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <span>Product Category: </span>
    <select style="width: 200px" class="productcategory" id="prod_cat_id">

        <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">-Select-</option>
        @foreach ($prod as $cat)
            <option value="{{ $cat->id }}">{{ $cat->product_cat_name }}</option>
        @endforeach

    </select>

    <span>Product Name: </span>
    <select style="width: 200px" class="productname">

        <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Product Name</option>
    </select>

    <span>Product Price: </span>
    <input type="text" class="prod_price">

</body>

</html>
```

This is my Scripts

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {


            $(document).on('change', '.productcategory', function() {
                // console.log("hmm its change");

                var cat_id = $(this).val();
                // console.log(cat_id);
                var div = $(this).parent();

                var op = " ";

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'get',
                    url: "{{ url('findProductName') }}",
                    data: {
                        'id': cat_id
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        //console.log('success');

                        console.log(data);

                        //console.log(data.length);
                        op += '<option value="0" selected disabled>chose product</option>';
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            op += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].productname +
                                '</option>';
                        }

                        div.find('.productname').html(" ");
                        div.find('.productname').append(op);
                    },
                    error: function() {

                    }
                });
            });

            $(document).on('change', '.productname', function() {
                var prod_id = $(this).val();

                var a = $(this).parent();
                console.log(prod_id);
                var op = "";
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'get',
                    url: '{!! URL::to('findPrice') !!}',
                    data: {
                        'id': prod_id
                    },
                    dataType: 'json', //return data will be json
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log("price");
                        console.log(data.price);

                        // here price is column name in products table data.coln name

                        a.find('.prod_price').val(data.price);

                    },
                    error: function() {

                    }
                });


            });

        });
    </script>
```

This is my CategoryController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Category;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

use App\Models\ProductCat;
use App\Models\Product;


class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function prodfunct()
    {

        $prod = ProductCat::all(); //get data from table
        return view('productlist', compact('prod')); //sent data to view

    }

    public function findProductName(Request $request)
    {


        //if our chosen id and products table prod_cat_id col match the get first 100 data 

        //$request->id here is the id of our chosen option id
        $data = Product::select('productname', 'id')->where('prod_cat_id', $request->id)->take(100)->get();
        return response()->json($data); //then sent this data to ajax success
    }


    public function findPrice(Request $request)
    {

        //it will get price if its id match with product id
        $p = Product::select('price')->where('id', $request->id)->first();

        return response()->json($p);
    }
}
```

this is my web route

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController;


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/prodview','App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController@prodfunct');
Route::get('/findProductName','App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController@findProductName');
Route::get('/findPrice','App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController@findPrice');
```

Comment: See the Laravel log file for more information about the error and post the error in your question.